# angular create table from nested json

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a table using nested json in an elasticsearch response.

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "took": 18,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 94,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [

        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "byDateTime": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1232037318222,
                    "key_as_string": "2012/01/12 16:34:18.000",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "byRecordNum": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": 4876,
                                "doc_count": 2,
                                "byhash": {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                    "buckets": [
                                        {
                                            "key": "632854032d8e042ec124dbfad12e214a",
                                            "doc_count": 2,
                                            "byContent": {
                                                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                                "buckets": [
                                                    {
                                                        "key": "useraction",
                                                        "doc_count": 2,
                                                        "tophits": {
                                                            "hits": {
                                                                "total": 2,
                                                                "max_score": 1.0,
                                                                "hits": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "_index": "myIndex",
                                                                        "_type": "log",
                                                                        "_id": "AVMN9FCKyxgCcpqsf1n3",
                                                                        "_score": 1.0,
                                                                        "_source": {
                                                                            "Field1": "Value1",
                                                                            "Field2": "Value2",
                                                                            "Field3": "Value3"
                                                                    }
```

The values that I need to access for the table are contained in the hits.hits section at the end.

In the controller I assign:

```
$scope.selectedactionhits = response.aggregations.byDateTime.buckets;
```

And then I can access the elements that I need using the following:

```
div ng-repeat="item in selectedactionhits">
    <div ng-repeat="a in item.byRecordNum.buckets">
    <div ng-repeat="b in a.byhash.buckets">

      <div ng-repeat="c in b.byContent.buckets">
        <div ng-repeat="d in c.tophits.hits.hits">
          {{d._source.Field1}}
          {{d._source.Field2}}
          {{d._source.Field3}}
```

What I need to do is create a table using the values form these fields, however as they are nested inside ng-repeat the table formatting does not work.

I've considered doing something in the controller to sort out the json, however I'm not sure how to do that.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Likely best to flatten this data in controller

Comment: I'd highly recommend you normalize your data. Figure out exactly what you need from the response and bind only that to the view.

Comment: I've been trying to flatten this data, however I'm not able to get that to work in the controller. Do you know how I could do that? Thanks!

Comment: Similar loops to what you already have in view...push desired items into a new array.

Comment: Thanks, would you do this entirely in the controller? I'm trying to do that and that and when I do a push into a new array, all I seem to be getting is the key and not the object. Also, how do I loop through each object in the array?

Answer (score 2):

After some cleaning of the JSON I came to what i think is the most simple [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/fswkps4TfSe4NQpjYxjU?p=preview). Using JSON.stringify and passing a function to the second parameter that will save the hits in an array.

```
function retrievehits (key, v) {
  if (key === 'hits' && v) {
    var isArray = Array.isArray(v);
    if (!isArray) {
      hits.push(JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, v, {hits: undefined})));
    }
    else if (isArray) {
      for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        retrievehits('hits', v[i]);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
  return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses. I've found a solution that seems to be working.

In the controller I have:

```
var flat = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.selectedactionhits, function(item){

          //second level
          angular.forEach(item.byRecordNum.buckets, function(item2){

            //Third level
            angular.forEach(item2.byhash.buckets, function(item3){

              //Fourth level
              angular.forEach(item3.byContent.buckets, function(item4){

                //fith level
                angular.forEach(item4.tophits.hits.hits, function(item5){
                  flat.push(item5);
                })
              })
            })
          })
        })
$scope.flatarray = flat;
```

And I can now use:

```
ng-repeat item in flatarray
```

and then get each element as:

```
{{item._source.Field1}}
```